# How to customized SpinnerItemStyle with styles.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-spinner, android-styles

I tried to customize a spinnerItem with styles file. I can change spinner style (bg, border or font color etc.) but spinnerItem has always white colored text and grayed background.

do you have any idea?

ps: I shouldn't use new adapter for this.

This is my styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItemTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerTheme" parent="Edit">
    <item name="android:background">@color/blueColor</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@color/darkRedColor</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItemTheme</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItemTheme</item>
</style>
<style name="Edit" parent="Text.Display">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">top|left</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerItemTheme" parent="SpinnerTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/blueColor</item>
</style>
```

This is my layout file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                style="@style/SpinnerTheme"
                android:prompt="@string/prompt_nation"
                android:entries="@array/countries">
                </android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner>
```

Comment: try this for style - http://android-holo-colors.com/

Comment: Already tried this. Exported a example then I import and run. Result same.

Comment: try my below answer may its help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code :

```
<resources>
   <style name="customtheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
      <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
      <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item>
   </style>
   <style name="SpinnerItem">
      <item name="android:textColor">@color/your_color</item>
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/your_backgroung</item>
   </style>
   <style name="SpinnerDropDownItem">
      <item name="android:textColor">@color/your_color</item>
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/your_background</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: change nothing :\

Comment: This works - even when using an AppCompat base theme.  I actually replace `android:spinnerStyle` as well (just `spinnerStyle` if using an AppCompat base theme).  `spinnerStyle` is where I set the background for the spinner itself. `spinnerItemStyle` allows for changing things such as font and padding for the text inside the spinner.

Answer (score 1):

styles.xml:

```html
  <style name="ToolbarSpinner" parent="AppTheme">
  <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/ToolbarSpinnerItem</item>
  <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/ToolbarSpinnerDropDownItem</item>
 </style>

 <style name="ToolbarSpinnerItem" parent="TextMedium">
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/material_grey_white_1000</item>
  <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
 </style>

 <style name="ToolbarSpinnerDropDownItem" parent="TextMedium">
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/material_grey_black_1000</item>
  <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
  <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/space_small</item>
  <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/space_small</item>
 </style>
```

layout:

```html
<Spinner
  android:id="@+id/spinner"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:spinnerMode="dialog"
  android:theme="@style/ToolbarSpinner"/>
```

onCreateView:

```js
spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(spinner.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listSource);

spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

Note that ArrayAdapter should be initialized with spinner.getContext(), because this context contains needed theme